# Android data binding, Select value of RadioGroup when click button submit

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, data-binding

I have a RadioGroup consisting of 2 choices and a button, After I press that button I want to get the value and based on that value I want to perform different actions:

```
 <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg_select"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_a"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mo_512dp"
                android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                android:text="Visual Advance" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                android:text="Visual basic" />
        </RadioGroup>

   <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click"
            onSingleClick="@{() -> onClickListener.getRadioButton()}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rg_select">
```

```
   fun getRadioButton() {
        val result = rg_select.checkedRadioButtonId
        when (genderId) {
            R.id.rb_a -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "KKSKSK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            R.id.rb_b -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "KKSKSK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

    }
```

But my above code is not suitable for databinding so can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can't see any obstacle for it. Just handle two actions separately, when radio button is checked "android:checked="@{viewModel.selectedRG.equals(RG.A)}", when button pressed onSingleClick="@{viewModel.performSomeAction()}". So in this case when performSomeAction() will be invoked RG type can be taken from "selectedRG".
If smth missed, let me know.